# What specific method is called when someone presses a key on the Iphone/ipad keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, keyboard

The reason I ask is because I'm creating a custom keyboard and I wanted to know what method I need to implement to emulate the general behavior of a standard keyboard.

Looking at the docs for the UIKeyInput protocol, the way the text responds to the keyboard is

```
- (void) insertText:(NSString *) theText {

[self.theString appendString:theText];

}
```

So does the keyboard call the `insertText:` method, or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating your custom keyboard, then you probably don't need the UIKeyInput protocol, cause it is used with the standard text input system.

Comment: But wouldn't it be convenient to use the protocol, considering that it keeps me from having to start from scratch?

Comment: Yes, you can use that protocol, but I don't think that defining your own protocol that contains 3 methods is starting from scratch.